# Passing a Constant into a method, leading to syntax errors. Splat operator in use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a code snippet which produces a flattened array of a models attribute names and setter equivalents, then uses the splat operator to pass this array as a variables to `Module.delegate()`, delegating all `User.attributes` to the BaseUser class. This works fine.

See https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

```
class BaseUser
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :user

  # The code snippet described above
  delegate(*::User.attribute_names.map {|attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: :user)

  def initialize(user_attributes)
    @user = ::User.new(user_attributes)
  end
end
```

Now, I wish to re-write this snippet as method which can take the `[ModelName] < ActiveRecord::Base` class constant as a parameter. However, my attempt (below) results in several syntax errors. Where am I going wrong?

```
def delegate_getters_and_setters(model)
   delegate(*::model.attribute_names.map {|attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: model.downcase.to_sym)
end
```

Thanks for the help!

**Edit:**

Here are the syntax errors highlighted by Sublime Text 3.

```
-:6: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting tCONSTANT
      delegate(*::model.attribute_names.map {|attr| ...
                       ^
-:6: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
...ttr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: model.downcase.to_sym)
...                               ^
-:6: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
```

Comment: What exactly are you passing to the method `delegate_getters_and_setters` as model?

Comment: Can you post the several errors that you are facing... ;)

Comment: Hi Tukan. I have not gotten that far but, I would pass `User` or `Company` etc. Defining the method as above is incorrect, I receive multiple syntax errors. I'm unsure how to write the method in a syntactically valid way.

Comment: Edited to include errors for you, @VamsiKrishna.

Comment: @PatrickQuigley could you describe the relation between `BaseUser` and `User`? I would have assumed that `User` inherits from `BaseUser`, i.e. `class User < BaseUser` but apparently, `BaseUser` contains an instance of `User` and delegates to that instance. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Stefan I'm creating a multi-step, multi-model Wizard. With all additional models being created as nested attributes of User. It's going well so far. I've relied heavily on Nicolas Blanco's post here: https://medium.com/@nicolasblanco/developing-a-wizard-or-multi-steps-forms-in-rails-d2f3b7c692ce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::model` makes no sense. `model` is a local variable. Just remove double colon in front of it:

```
delegate(*model.attrib......
```

Comment: Depending on your scope, you might have to prepend `::` to your constant when calling the method, i.e. `delegate_getters_and_setters(::User)`

Answer (score 3):

> Now, I wish to re-write this snippet as method which can take the `[ModelName] < ActiveRecord::Base` class constant as a parameter.

You can't take a constant as a parameter. You can only take objects as parameters. Constants aren't objects.

> However, my attempt (below) results in several syntax errors. Where am I going wrong?

You are assuming that you are getting the constant as an argument. But you don't. When someone calls

```
delegate_setters_and_getters(Foo)
```

You are not getting the constant `Foo` as an argument. You can't, because the constant `Foo` is not an object. Instead, the constant `Foo` is dereferenced at the call site, and you get whatever object `Foo` resolves to (presumably a class) at the call site as an argument.

It's exactly the same as with any other expression. If you call

```
delegate_setters_and_getters(foo)
```

you are *not* passing the local variable `foo` as an argument, you are passing the object that `foo` references as an argument. (In fact, you *couldn't* pass the local variable as an argument, even if you wanted to, because variables aren't objects.)

If you call

```
delegate_setters_and_getters(bar.baz)
```

you are *not* passing the method call `bar.baz` as an argument, you are calling the method `baz` on the object obtained by dereferencing the local variable `bar` and then passing the return value of that method call as an argument. (And again, method calls aren't objects, so you couldn't pass them even if you wanted to.)

Comment: So, if I call `delegate_setters_and_getters(User)` I am passing in as an argument what `User` resolves to. Which in my exmaple is the object which represents the class `User < ActiveRecord::Base`, which is itself an instance of the class `Class`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You don't have to resolve the constant to a class, you get passed the class.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @mudasobwa says:

`::` is a part of constant's fully-qualified name (FQN) syntax. Leading `::` helps disambiguate name resolution.

In your case, in `delegate_getters_and_setters` constant name is already resolved and `model` is a reference to the constant<sup>*</sup>, whatever it is.

---

<sub>* where by "reference to the constant" I mean "reference to the same object that the constant points to", of course.</sub>

Comment: Done and noted for next time.